# Segmenting a video results in incorrect timecode data

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

When I segment a video file into 5-second chunks:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_format mp4 chunk-%d.mp4
```

Each chunk is exactly 5 seconds long, but when playing the video in something like VLC, the timecodes look like:

[image]

Where on the right, it shows the correct video duration (5 seconds) but on the left, it shows the time at which it would be if you were viewing it in the original file.

How can I ensure that each video file has the correct timecode data (preferably without re-encoding)?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/863183/how-to-fix-ffmpeg-inaccurate-time-stamp-that-corrupts-thumbnail-generation) describes a similar issue to mine but the only solution there is to copy the codecs, which my command above already does.

Comment: Have you try to add `-reset_timestamps`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Didn't even know that was an option but adding it worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I add it in to answer. Is you are happy with this feel free to upvote and/or accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option which exist is to add `-reset_timestamps 1` to the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 5 -segment_format mp4 chunk-%d.mp4
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I've just submitted an edit - `-reset_timestamps` needs to have a `1` added after it in order to work, otherwise it returns an error.